# I get a "password expired" notification when i try to login my oracle 11g express edition. Can anybody help me out resolving this issue? :(

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I get a "password expired" notification when i try to login to my oracle 11g express edition. If I enter a different password all I end up seeing is an "Invalid login credentials" notification. Can anybody help me out resolving this issue? :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the grace period, you need to reset the password. e.g.

```
ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY "password";
```

If the account is locked, you can unlock it (you will need to login as a higher privileged user, such as SYSTEM):

```
ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a one simple trick if you have install oracle in your personal system.

Press CTRL+R-- Run--WINDOWS.

Type : sqlplus.exe

Prompt will ask you user name: Type user-name which is expired.
now type the password.

it will notifies you the password is expire, after that just type new password.

Done !

Answer (score 1):

(Solution on windows) Open your command line `sqlplus`.
Then it will ask your username, enter expired username. Then it will ask for password, enter current password. It will say that your password has expired, and asks you to change it. Enter new password and done!